# ASP.NET MVC 3 user Profiles not being generated

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

For my ASP.NET MVC 3 app (using Razor) my `web.config` has this:

```
<profile>
  <providers>
    <clear/>
    <add name="AspNetSqlProfileProvider" type="System.Web.Profile.SqlProfileProvider" connectionStringName="ApplicationServices" applicationName="/" />
  </providers>
  <properties>
    <add name="FirstName"/>
    <add name="LastName"/>
  </properties>
</profile>
```

It is my understanding from reading the docs that ASP.NET will automatically generate properties off the HttpContext so that I can access these like this:

```
 // MyController.cs

 Email = u.Email;
 FirstName = HttpContext.Profile.FirstName;
 LasttName = HttpContext.Profile.LastName;
```

However, the compiler is bitching that `.FirstName` and `.LastName` don't exist.

What is going on here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this approach:

1. Create a class (name it `UserProfile` for example) extending `ProfileBase`
2. Add your public properties `Email` etc (don't forget `{get;set;}`)
3. Change your Web.config like the following (change the inherits to your namespace)
4. You should be able to access it now via `(UserProfile)HttpContext.Current.Profile`

---

Your Web.config:

```
<profile defaultProvider="AspNetSqlProfileProvider" inherits="Namespace.To.Your.UserProfile">
    <providers>
        <clear/>
        <add name="AspNetSqlProfileProvider" connectionStringName="ConnectionStringName" type="System.Web.Profile.SqlProfileProvider" applicationName="App" />
    </providers>
</profile>
```

---

Your profile class:

```
public class UserProfile : ProfileBase
{
    public string Email
    {
        get { return (string)GetPropertyValue("Email"); }
        set { SetPropertyValue("Email", value); }
    }
}
```

Comment: that works. Thanks. But would you mind explaining why the documented behavior is not working?

Comment: I dont believe in mvc apps the ids get compiled the same way they do in a web forms web application. some prob I think with web site v. web application

Comment: The answer is my project is a web app not a web site and the compilation does not happen for web apps.  This article was really helpful: http://leedumond.com/blog/asp-net-profiles-in-web-application-projects/

Comment: ya thats what I meant - just the other way around

Comment: Good to know for me as well - I figured it out a long time ago and didn't know the reason why the documented behavior wasn't working. So learning by answering for me ;)

Comment: Marc, now I find that if I use `UserProfile` as a model, my view barfs on a POST. I get `...GetPropertyValue("FirstName")...can't find FirstName...`.  Do you pass these `ProfileBased` derived classes as Models and have them work???

Comment: No I don't use them as models and I don't think they should used this way. You have to built your own view model with the same property names, so you could add validation in your viewmodel etc, and then pass the properties to the UserProfile object - either manually or with something like AutoMapper

Answer (score 0):

When using ASP.NET Web Forms, the profile data is accessed through a proxy object whose properties correspond to the profile properties. This feature isn't available for MVC Framework applications.
u can get user profile property value just like this:

```
public ActionResult Index() 
{
    ViewBag.Name = HttpContext.Profile["Name"];
    ViewBag.City = HttpContext.Profile.GetProfileGroup("Address")["City"];
    return View();
}
```

it will return current logged in user profile property value.